# Interesting bitwise operation

Tags: c, sha1, bitwise-operators

I came across some rather interesting code today while reviewing an implementation of SHA1 in C.

```
temp = SHA1CircularShift(5,A) + (B ^ C ^ D) + E + W[t] + K[1];
temp &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

The part I find interesting is `temp &= 0xFFFFFFFF;`. Note that `temp` is declared as an **unsigned integer** already. Won't this operation simply have no effect? The only thing I can think of is that the designer is trying to enforce the use of 32-bit integers, but wouldn't this be done at compile-time?
I'm curious to know peoples thoughts.

Comment: What is the *exact type* of `temp`?

Comment: On some machines, `int` (or `unsigned int`) could be a 64-bit type.  The mask is a no-op on machines where `int` is a 32-bit type, but critical on machines where it is a 64-bit type.  The compiler will know and will optimize the operation away when it does nothing useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some machines, `int` (and therefore `unsigned int` too) could be a 64-bit type. The mask is a no-op on machines where `int` is a 32-bit type, but critical on machines where it is a 64-bit type. The compiler will know and will optimize the operation away when it does nothing useful.

Also, there used to be machines with [36-bit `int` types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-bit) and others with [60-bit `int` types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/60-bit); it would matter on such machines too.

Answer (score 2):

The [reference implementation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3174) of SHA1, have the following note in comments:

```
/*
 *  sha1.c
 *
 *  Description:
 *      This file implements the Secure Hashing Algorithm 1 as
 *      defined in FIPS PUB 180-1 published April 17, 1995.
 *
 *      The SHA-1, produces a 160-bit message digest for a given
 *      data stream.  It should take about 2**n steps to find a
 *      message with the same digest as a given message and
 *      2**(n/2) to find any two messages with the same digest,
 *      when n is the digest size in bits.  Therefore, this
 *      algorithm can serve as a means of providing a
 *      "fingerprint" for a message.
 *
 *  Portability Issues:
 *      SHA-1 is defined in terms of 32-bit "words".  This code
 *      uses <stdint.h> (included via "sha1.h" to define 32 and 8
 *      bit unsigned integer types.  If your C compiler does not
 *      support 32 bit unsigned integers, this code is not
 *      appropriate.
 *
 *  Caveats:
 *      SHA-1 is designed to work with messages less than 2^64 bits
 *      long.  Although SHA-1 allows a message digest to be generated
 *      for messages of any number of bits less than 2^64, this
 *      implementation only works with messages with a length that is
 *      a multiple of the size of an 8-bit character.
 *
 */
```

The `Portability Issues` is the case for this operation in this implementation of SHA1, it allows it to function properly on machines with larger `int`s.